# Command substitution grepping ls output causes error

Tags: shell, files, backup, tar, command-substitution

I'm trying to make a tar.tgz file using command substitution

There are backups of 17 Aug 2012

```
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502 804M Aug 17  2012 BKPMDISINT_i6nir20j.F_bkp
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502 2.7G Aug 17  2012 BKPSYFINT_i5nir20j.F_bkp
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502 3.9G Aug 17  2012 BKPMSFFINT_i4nir20j.F_bkp
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502  28M Aug 17  2012 c-651746692-20120817-00
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502 2.0G Aug 17  2012 ALG_KLPFINT_ianir576.alg
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502 1.5G Aug 17  2012 ALG_KLPFINT_i8nir576.alg
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502  37M Aug 17  2012 ALG_KLPINT_ibnir64h.alg
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502 2.2G Aug 17  2012 ALG_KLPFINT_i9nir576.alg
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502  28M Aug 17  2012 c-651746692-20120817-01
-rw-r----- 1 ossec  502  27M Aug 17  2012 ctrl_170803
```

So i need to tar them. I used this command

> tar -zcvf DB-Backup-17082012.tgz $(ls -lrth|grep "Aug 17")

But it gave me this error

```
tar: You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux' option
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Comment: You do realize that the `ls -l | grep "Aug 17"` will also match files modified on Aug 17 within the past six months, as well as any file which happens to have "Aug 17" in its name, right? Generally, [never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). I suggest looking at using `find`, and paying particular attention to `-daystart` and `-mtime`.

Comment: Also that command won't work because your sending the entire line of output from `ls -l` to `tar`. You need to cut it up with either the `cut` command or `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your way

You can surely do what you want but it is probably dangerous given some files might have spaces in their names. Here's one way to do it though.

```
$ tar -zcvf DB-Backup-17082012.tgz $(ls -lrth|grep "Aug 17"|awk '{print $9}')
```

This will get rid of all the other column data that you're getting from the `ls -lrth` and just give you the file names.

#### Using find & tar: method #1

You can use the Unix `find` command to get a list of all the files that were last modified on a given date and pipe this list to `tar` as follows:

```
$ find . -type f -newermt 2012-08-17 ! -newermt 2012-08-18 -print0 | \
   xargs -0 tar zcvf DB-Backup-17082012.tgz
```

The above will only find files that were last modified on 2012-08-17 but nothing newer. The `-print0` tells find to split the files that it outputs using null characters (`\0`) and the `xargs -0` takes each of these files and builds up invocations of `tar` adding the files in batches at a time.

This is probably the least performant way to do this.

**NOTE:** This method also runs the risk of losing files if your have more than can be passed as command line arguments to the `tar` command.

#### Using find & tar: method #2

The `-print0` and the `xargs -0` are redundant and you can use just `find` to generate the list and call `tar` directly:

```
$ find . -type f -newermt 2012-08-17 ! -newermt 2012-08-18 \
   -exec tar zcvf DB-Backup-17082012.tgz {} \+
```

The `{} \+` arguments to find above will do 2 things. The `{}` will substitute the name of each file as `find` finds it in this position when calling `tar` and the `\+` tells `find` to keep putting as many files as it can on the command line before calling `tar`. This saves you on having to invoke `tar` 100 times if you have 100 files to add to it.

#### References

- [find man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)
- [tar man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar)

Comment: I hope you realise that if you "xargs tar" and the commandline becomes too long `tar` will be started multiple times and only the last version is maintained. The number of chars is large (100K or so), but I have seen `xargs` invoke its commands multiple times in real life.

Comment: @Anthon - Thanks I'll add the clarification.

Comment: @Anthon These days the default limit on Linux is 2MB (it was 128kB for a long time). This reduces the risk in practice, but doesn't eliminate it.

Comment: @Gilles - do you happen to know if the `\+` option would suffer from the same issue then?

Comment: @slm Yes, it works in exactly the same way. The limit is in the kernel (maximum memory that the `execve` system call may allocate). `find -exec +` = `xargs` without the quoting issues.

Comment: @Giles - thanks! So I guess if you're really concerned about it then you're better to run the files from the `find` to a `<file>`, and then `tar -T <file>`.

Comment: @Giles Thanks, did not know that. That is still only 50K files with an average path length of 40 chars. I wondered a long time ago why `xargs` has no `--only-single-invocation` option to prevent it from running at all if the commandline becomes too long.

Comment: Besides the weird quoting in `grep "Aug 17"|awk '{print $9'}`, note also that this is equivalent to `awk '/Aug 17/{print $9}'`.  See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep

Comment: @tripleee - yeah the weird quoting was a typo, I fixed it, thanks for pointing it out. As to the `grep`, put that comment on the OP's question, since they were using it, I'm showing it so they understand a limitation in their approach  with using `grep` on `ls` output.

Answer (score 6):

If you do `$(ls -lrth|grep "Aug 17")` you get the whole line, not just the filenames as argument to `tar`, so that will not work. In general you should **not parse** the output of `ls`.

What you can do if you have relatively recent version of Gnu find ( >= v4.3.3 ) is

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt 20120817T0000 -not -newermt 20130818T0000 -print0 \
    | cpio --create --null  --format=ustar \
    | gzip > DB-Backup-17082012.tgz
```

If your `find` does not support `-newermt` you can create two files with touch with those date-timestamps and just use -newer. Of course you can also use `-daystart -mtime`  but you would need to calculate the number of days (or use trial and error).

One recommendation I have is to use dates in files in the form YYYYMMDD. First of the sort nicer if you have multiple files that start with the same string up to the date and second something like 05062012 would be ambiguous depending on the person looking at the file name ( June 5th (Europe) or May 6th (USA)). So although 1708 has to be August 17th, I would call the file `DB-Backup-20120817.tgz`

Answer (score 0):

Your current format `ls|grep "Aug 17"` does not output anything. Instead, use the following format:

```
$ ls -ltr  | grep 'Aug 17'
```

Comment: Oh sorry it was ls -lrth , I copied the wrong command. Question updated

Answer (score -1):

regarding the `$(ls -lrth|grep "Aug 17")` this awk line would probably extract the dates you want:

```
$(ls -lrth|awk '/Aug/&&/17{print $0}')
```

Comment: You should point out that this only works for the limited list of filenames provided. In general the output of ls cannot be processed (filenames might contain spaces and/or newlines etc.)

Comment: ah your right, though in this particular case it works (which has me questioning the downvote...)

Comment: If you answer something on SX you should IMHO take care to point where the limitations are. Someone else might come up with a similar situation but not so well behaved files and would not understand why it does work for him/her. (It was not me who downvoted, so someone else must think your answer is not so  useful).

Comment: I apologize, I should've added I didn't think it was you who downvoted me since your comment didn't seem completely negative. Either way I'm a complete beginner when it comes to this stuff so any feedback is welcome